# iframe doesnt show the correct frame

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to load iframe of bing, that show its navbar, but something wierd happens. when I load this it doesnt show the navbar but the search bar, but if I change (in the chrome inspector)the hieght from 35px to 3500px and then back to 35px. it shows the navbar.

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px none; position:absolute; left=0px; top=0px; margin-top: 0px; z-index:0; width:1700px; height:35px;"></iframe>
```

anyone have ideas why it happens?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/
This is where you can post your HTML,CSS, and JS and we can take a look at it in a live environment

Comment: @gibsonman507 You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/fb1da102/ it looks like some JavaScript in bing is being fired on page load to move the search bar to the top of the page.

Comment: thanks. here it is.
http://jsfiddle.net/1entzqvg/
but what happens here is that the page refresh when i run it so what happened in the browser didnt happen here. I edited my question so it will be clearer

Comment: It looks like the bing webpage itself is doing this on page load - to ensure the search bar is visible on small screens, it will hide the page is too small. This shows the behaviour you are describing - http://jsfiddle.net/7p0vjtjo/

Comment: can i get past it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's some JavaScript on Bing that's moving the search bar to the top on page load.

It seems you can get round this by hiding the iframe by default in CSS, then showing it on document ready using jQuery:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px none;
    position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; margin-top: 0px; z-index:0; width:1700px;
    height:35px; display: none;">
</iframe>

$(function () {
    $("iframe").show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fb1da102/5/)

Comment: Thanks!. realy helped me

Comment: @marcopolo No worries glad I could help, bit of a strange one.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use some javascript here and hiding initially seems to be the best way forward. You can do it in pure javascript by listening to the `load` event of the `iframe`, and *then* showing it:

```js
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('f').style.display = '';
});
```

```html
<iframe id="f" src="http://www.bing.com/" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px none; position:absolute; left=0px; top=0px; margin-top: 0px; z-index:0; width:1700px; height:35px; display:none;"></iframe>
```